# Python error converted from a Java code

Tags: java, python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I am trying to learn python. So, I have a following Java code to print the list of the factors of the entered number. I am trying to implement the same logic in python. But getting some errors. The java code is as follows:

```
public final class PrintFactors {

private PrintFactors() {}

public static void printFactors(int number) {
    if (number <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number should be greater than 0.");
    printFactorsList(number, number + "*" + 1 + "\n", number);
}

private static void printFactorsList(int dividend, String factorString, int prevDivisor) {

    for (int divisor = dividend - 1; divisor >= 2; divisor--) {

        if (dividend % divisor != 0)
            continue;

        if (divisor > prevDivisor)
            continue;

        int quotient = dividend / divisor;


        if (quotient <= divisor) {
            if (quotient <= prevDivisor) {
                System.out.println(factorString + divisor + "*" + quotient);
            }
        }
        printFactorsList(quotient, factorString + divisor + "*", divisor);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printFactors(12);
    System.out.println();
    printFactors(32);
}
```

}

The above code outputs the result as follows:

```
 $ java -cp . PrintFactors 32
```

32 * 1

16 * 2

8 * 4

8 * 2 * 2

4 * 4 * 2

4 * 2 * 2 * 2

2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2

My python code is as follows:

```
def print_factors_list(dividend, factorstring, predivisor):

divisor = dividend - 1
for i in range(int(divisor), 2, -1 ):
    if dividend % i != 0:
        continue

    if divisor > predivisor:
        continue

    quotient = dividend / divisor


    if quotient <= divisor:
        if quotient <= predivisor:
            print factorstring + str(divisor) + "*" + str(quotient)


print_factors_list(quotient, str(factorstring) + str(divisor) + "*", divisor)


def print_factors(x):
if (x < 0):
    print "Enter a positive interger"
else:
    print_factors_list(x, str(x) + "*" + str(1) + "\n", x )

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print_factors(num)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined: Error: local variable 'quotient' referenced before assignment
```

Please can someone help me with this where am I going wrong. Is there a logic error as I have implemented the steps as the Java code? Thanks.

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: @MattDMo Still not giving desired output? Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Python is indentation-sensitive. You had your `print_factors_list` recursive call at the outermost indentation level, thus it's outside of the `for` loop. This is different behaviour from your Java code.

Comment: Any recommendations on changes? I tried putting it in for loop. It does not give me the desired output